# Angular 2 load components only from root/app folder

Tags: javascript, angular

I have created an angular2 project with angular-cli(version 1.0.0-beta.8, angular version is 2.0.0-rc.3)
Running `ng new` or `ng init` creates this directory structure:

```
  create .editorconfig
  create README.md
  create src\app\app.component.css
  create src\app\app.component.html
  create src\app\app.component.spec.ts
  create src\app\app.component.ts
  create src\app\environment.ts
  create src\app\index.ts
  create src\app\shared\index.ts
  create src\favicon.ico
  create src\index.html
  create src\main.ts
  create src\system-config.ts
  create src\tsconfig.json
  create src\typings.d.ts
  create angular-cli-build.js
  create angular-cli.json
  create config\environment.dev.ts
  create config\environment.js
  create config\environment.prod.ts
  create config\karma-test-shim.js
  create config\karma.conf.js
  create config\protractor.conf.js
  create e2e\app.e2e-spec.ts
  create e2e\app.po.ts
  create e2e\tsconfig.json
  create e2e\typings.d.ts
  create .gitignore
  create package.json
  create public\.npmignore
  create tslint.json
  create typings.json
```

When I generate a component (ng g component my-component) it adds a folder my-component in the src\app folder with the component files(ts, css, html, etc...)

When I import my-component component in the app(the main one) component and put it in the html:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MyComponentComponent } from './my-component';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.css'],
  directives: [MyComponentComponent]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';
}
```

app.component.html:

```
<h1>
  {{title}}
</h1>
<app-my-component></app-my-component>
```

everything works.

If I create a folder (named "project" in that case) and move my-component folder there (`src\app\project\my-component`) and import the component from there:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MyComponentComponent } from './project/my-component'; //chnaged "./my-component" to "./project/my-component"

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.css'],
  directives: [MyComponentComponent]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';
}
```

The application is compiled, but in the browser I get:

```
zone.js:101 GET http://localhost:4200/app/project/my-component.js 404 (Not Found)
```

Is it a bug or I'm missing something?

Edit:

All the components are correctly compiled irrespective of the folder.

The strange thing is that the application wants to load `my-component.js` while the generated file is `my-component.component.js` (this works the same with other names. "component" in the name is not an issue)

When the component folder is in the app folder the application correctly loads `my-component.component.js`

Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Seems something issue your my-component.ts file. Most probably template file path.

Answer (score 1):

Check if in the new folder (project) you have the component typescript compiled files (*.js and *js.map)

See also you code for the Component-Relative URLs to component templates and style files:

> The Angular 2 CLI uses these technologies and defaults to the
>   component-relative path approach
>   described here. CLI users can skip this chapter or read on to
>   understand how it works.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-relative-paths.html

**UPDATE1**

1) create a new folder "project" inside src/app

2) run in terminal:

```
ng generate component project/my-component2
```

(see: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#generating-components-directives-pipes-and-services )

this will generate your component and all dependencies relative to this new folder (project)

3) change your app.component.ts and html to view the components.

Below is the example-code for 2 components (1 in src/app and 1 in src/app/project/) :

**my-component.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  templateUrl: 'my-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['my-component.component.css']
})
export class MyComponentComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**my-component2.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-my-component2',
  templateUrl: 'my-component2.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['my-component2.component.css']
})
export class MyComponent2Component implements OnInit {

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MyComponentComponent } from './my-component/my-component.component';
import { MyComponent2Component } from './project/my-component2/my-component2.component';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.css'],
  directives: [
    MyComponentComponent,
    MyComponent2Component
  ]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<h1>
  {{title}}
</h1>
<app-my-component></app-my-component>
<app-my-component2></app-my-component2>
```

For me this works fine

[image]
[image]

Comment: i think the same thing i mentioned in my answer @Gabi ?

Comment: I think we have answered in the same time but yours is not mentioning the relatives URLs btw

Comment: can you try to replace your import statement with : import { MyComponentComponent } from './project/my-component.component'

Comment: @Gabi I get a compilation error "Cannot find module"

Comment: The correct import should be : import { MyComponentComponent } from './project/my-component/my-component.component'; (with folder for feature also, see my update; I've manage to fix this with two components : 1 in app and 1 in a folder called project

Comment: is working also if you will just copy the component folder into the new folder (project; without running ng generate with a relative path) and restart the app (but make sure that you correct the import statement before)

Answer (score 0):

Probaly your mistake is at the time of compilation (from .ts to .js)

I mean when you create component it works fine, but when you switch your component to another folder named `project` (whatever) angular tries to find out file from `app/project/my-component.js` but your existing file location is `app/my-component.js` (see in your dist folder). so just stop the Project and try using Re Running your project by doing so all files will genrate with exact location and your project works

Comment: strange seriously :(